# how to convert string data(from input form) to integer data(to db)? Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, database, string, integer, laravel-8

I am a newbie in laravel. I have a little problem. I am confused how to convert form input data to db. I want when filling out the form input field it's in the form of a STRING, but I want the db to receive data as an integer.
What should I do?

In my blade :

```
<label class="form-label mb-3"><b>Category</b></label>
<input name="category_id" class="form-control  @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror" list="datalistOptions" id="category_id" placeholder="Ketik untuk mencari jenis kategori pertanyaan">
<datalist id="datalistOptions">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
       <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ old('category_id') == $category->name ? 'selected' : null }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</datalist>
@error('category_id')
<div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

In my controller

```
$validated = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'category_id' => 'required|nullable',
        'question_detail' => 'required|string',
    ]);
```

Please help

Comment: Question: What issue are you running into? php has functions to explicitly convert data, like `intVal()` or `doubleVal()`. you can also do `$stringContainingNumber+0` to convert it to its closest number(int for round numbers and double/float for fractions)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the validation `numeric`?

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|string',
    'category_id' => 'required|nullable',
    'question_detail' => 'required|string',
    'your_number_field' => 'required|numeric'
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-numeric

You may need to pair this with a numeric form field, on the input, like so: `type="number"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 0):

form data is always passed as a string.
You need to convert the variable in the backend.
Description: https://www.tutorialkart.com/php/php-convert-string-to-int/